# ionic 3 content background is not working

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

i am having trouble with changing background image,

html:

```
<ion-content padding class="arkaplan">
```

scss:

```
.arkaplan {

    background-image: url("../../../www/img/arkaplan.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

with this nothing changes.

i check some similar topics and some of them solved the issue with this:

```
background: url("../../../www/img/arkaplan.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
```

but that way, i am getting an error in chrome like:

```
GET http://localhost:8100/www/img/arkaplan.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

and black background. but if i put a web url to image it works. so basically app cant find my file but my directory is correct.

thanks for your support..

Comment: keep your image inside src/assets/img/arkaplan.jpg. Don't keep your image inside www folder. And After keeping your image inside src..... Then try access it like this "background-image: url('assets/img/arkaplan.jpg');

Comment: Thanks! this one worked. but background-image still not working i did it with background only.